# Overwrite named route helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to add some logic to a named route / url helper:

```
# app/helpers/my_helper.rb

module MyHelper
  def article_path(obj, opts = {})
    opts.merge!(token: @redis.get("token"))
    super(obj, opts)
  end
end
```

I also like to get the same logic in every controller, so I included it in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include TokenRoutesHelper 
end
```

Inside a view, the helper get's overwritten and everything works fine. But inside a controller, it doesn't overwrite the `article_path` helper. I also tried to do a `prepend TokenRoutesHelper`, but this also doesn't work.

I had a look with pry on the methods, and it seems that Rails puts it's own named route helpers BEFORE any included helper, *even* when added via `prepend`:

```
[1] pry(#<ArticlesController>)> show-source article_path

From: /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:322:
Owner: #<Module:0x000055b67aa85bc0>
Visibility: public
Signature: article_path(*args)
Number of lines: 11

define_method(name) do |*args|
  last = args.last
  options = \
    case last
    when Hash
      args.pop
    when ActionController::Parameters
      args.pop.to_h
    end
  helper.call self, args, options
end
[2] pry(#<ArticlesController>)> show-source article_path --super

From: /usr/src/app/app/helpers/my_helper.rb:4:
Owner: MyHelper
Visibility: public
Signature: article_path(obj, opts = {})
Number of lines: 4

def article_path(obj, opts = {})
  opts.merge!(token: @redis.get("token"))
  super(obj, opts)
end
[3] pry(#<ArticlesController>)>
```

So, does Rails have a way to override it's auto generated url helpers?

Comment: If you want to override it everywhere why not just add it to the route instead of this overriding business?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to add custom logic to a route to control the behaviour of it's url helpers. Background: I'd like to append a parameter based on certain conditions. I've updated the question

Comment: Why not define a method in ApplicationController that doesn't override, but uses it instead? You could put the logic there if you want, but you don't have to override.

Comment: Because the helper is used a lot and I'd like to avoid reminding developers to use the new method as it could break functionality.